# How to sum the values of same vlookup results?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have this formula it gets the single data from another file from a sheet at column 7.

```
    =ARRAYFORMULA(
        if(
          len($A2:$A);
          iferror(
              vlookup(
                 $A2:$A;
                 importrange('Aylar ve Linkler'!$B$7;"Grafik Data'!$C3$:$J$108");
                 7;0);
                 "mağaza yok")
          ;)
      )
```

But the stores `vlookup($A2:$A)` on the other file's `Grafik Data'!$C3$:$J$108`sheet at 7th columns has 2 values and i want to sum them.

I mean when i look for store names on other file, there are 2 same store names with 2 different values. I would like to get `sum` of them.

[image: sample data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this : `Query`, `Filter` but I think `SUMIF` will suits the most :

```
=SUMIF(arrayformula(regexmatch(A1:A10;C1));true;B1:B10)

=SUM(FILTER(B1:B10;arrayformula(regexmatch(A1:A10;C1))))

=trim(REGEXREPLACE(CONCATENATE(QUERY(A1:B10;"SELECT sum(B) where A = '"&C1&"'"));"sum";))
```

Spreadsheet :

```
   A    |    B   |   C
--------------------------
Store 1 |    0   | Store 1
Store 1 |    12  |
Store 1 |    5   |
Store 2 |    0   |
Store 2 |    3   |
Store 2 |    4   |
Store 3 |    0   |
Store 3 |    8   |
Store 3 |    20  |
```

Result : `17`.
Because I used `Regexmatch`, you can't use it in a single `arrayformula`, you'll need to expand the formulas.

Comment: Thank you but on this formula (regexmatch(A1:A10;C1)) it is on different file. should i importrange? how can i do that?

Comment: =SUM(FILTER(B1:B10;arrayformula(regexmatch(A1:A10;C1)))) this worked! thanks

Comment: Yes, of course, you can use `importrange`, sorry I wasn't precise enough.

Comment: It is ok, thanks for the help!